# Setting up associations on CakePHP

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I am starting out trying to learn CakePHP and MVC in general.

I have a database with quite a few tables that I'm trying to associate and have been reading [the docs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html).

Here is an explanation of some of tables I have:

**`clients`** table, has fields:

- `id`
- `name`
- `currency`
- `risk_code_id` (this is a foreign key for the `risk_codes` table)

---

**`accounts`** table:

- `id`
- `client_id`
- ...some more fields relating to each account

---

**`risk_codes`** table:

- `id`
- `name`

I currently only have a Model for clients, which looks like this:

```
<?php
class Client extends AppModel {
    public $hasMany = 'Account';
    public $validate = array(
        'title' => array(
            'rule' => 'notEmpty'
        ),
        'body' => array(
            'rule' => 'notEmpty'
        )
    );
}
```

This retrieves the accounts relating to a client.

How would I associate the `risk_codes` table to `clients`? Do I need to make another model for risk_codes and define the association there? As should be quite obvious, each client has one risk code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html.

As the relationship client -> risk_code is "many to one", we say "Clients *belongs to* Risk Codes". So, you'll have to set this in two different ways:

**Client Model**

```
public $belongsTo = array(
    'RiskCode' => array(
        'className' => 'RiskCode',
        'foreignKey' => 'risk_code_id'
    )
);
```

**RiskCode Model**

```
public $hasMany = array(
    'Client' => array(
        'className' => 'Client',
        'foreignKey' => 'risk_code_id'
    )
);
```

There are many other options you can set while establishing these relationships, so checkout the CookBook for detailed information. :)

Comment: this seems to work. Now I need to figure out how to edit/add client records using the Clients Controller with the linked tables, but that's a different question

Comment: Yup. CakePHP pretty much does all the hard work when you link the models as you did, should you use [saveAll](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-saveall-array-data-null-array-options-array) to save data for all related models at once.

Comment: How would I make the `risk_code` appear in the edit view, assuming I currently have inputs for the `client` field in the form `echo $this->Form->input('name');`?

Comment: You can referrer to other models' fields using ModelName.FieldName, like `echo $this->Form->input('RiskCode.id');`

Answer (score 0):

you need to create the Client, Account and RiskCode models and define up the relationship for both directions between:

Client (hasMany) <---> Account (belongsTo)

Client (hasOne) <---> RiskCode (belongsTo)

Comment: What's the naming convention for models regarding table names with underscores, given risk_codes is like that?

Answer (score 0):

If Client has only one Risk code, then add field "client_id" to risk_codes table and attach it to Client:

```
public $hasOne = array(
        'RiskCode'
    );
```